# Проблемам с кодом в Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. 
Есть слайдер, вот его код:

```
    <?php 
$posts = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'category_name'    => 'slider',
    'orderby'     => 'date',
    'order'       => 'DESC',
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'suppress_filters' => true, 
) );

foreach( $posts as $post ){
    setup_postdata($post);
    ?>
    <div class="glide__slide">
        <div class="contetn">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
            <div class="text">
                <h3><?php the_title() ?></h3>
                <p><?php the_excerpt() ?></p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}

wp_reset_postdata(); // сброс                        
?>
```

Выпадает ошибка:

- Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-includes\class-wp-query.php on line 3252

Нашел этот файл в строке 3252 содержится:

- $this->post = $this->posts[ $this->current_post ];

Comment: Где стек вызовов? Какая строка вашего кода порождает эту ошибку? Возможно, что приведённый вами код вообще не имеет никакого отношения к ошибке.

Answer (score -1):

Проблему решил так, заменив этот кусок кода:

```
                        $posts = get_posts( array(
                        'numberposts' => -1,
                        'category_name'    => 'slider',
                        'orderby'     => 'date',
                        'order'       => 'DESC',
                        'post_type'   => 'post',
                        'suppress_filters' => true, 
                    ) );

                    foreach( $posts as $post ){
```

этим:

```
                    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 2 );
                    $lastposts = get_posts( $args );
                    foreach( $lastposts as $post ){
```

и все заработало!